# Apache 2 configuration port and root directory

Tags: apache2

Can everyone tell me how to make apache2 to listen ONLY on port 8080 and how to make root directory /home/alex/www

Answer (score 1):

You should use Listen or BindAddress to tell Apache2 what to listen to.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

To change the root directory, open a terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

then change the DocumentRoot path from /var/www to your desired directory